# Magento 2 Add special_to_date on products page

Tags: magento2

When there is a special price I'd like to show a text and "special_to_date" attribute under the products price.

I tried the following in a template file.. But it shows nothing.

```
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('special_to_date')-
>getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Special Price to date` using the below method with `product object`:

> $_product->getSpecialToDate();

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$specialprice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
$specialPriceFromDate = $product->getSpecialFromDate();
$specialPriceToDate = $product->getSpecialToDate();
$today =  time();

if ($specialprice && ($product->getPrice()>$product->getFinalPrice())):
    if($today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && $today <= strtotime($specialPriceToDate) || 
    $today >= strtotime( $specialPriceFromDate) && is_null($specialPriceToDate)):
    echo $specialPriceToDate //Product Special Price To Date
    endif; 
endif;
```